# Are all the identifiers for Windows Virtual Key Codes prefixed with VK_?

Tags: c, winapi

I am reading a excerpt from - [Charles Petzold's book on C++ Windows](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/petzold/ch06c.htm)

It states

> The virtual key codes you use most often have names beginning with VK_
>   defined in the WINUSER.H header file.

I have looked inside the WINUSER.H file, and from what I have seen all Virtual Key codes begin win VK_.

If this is not the case, can somebody point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Perhaps he means the VK codes for 0-9 and A-Z, which don't have corresponding `VK_` constants IIRC.

Comment: there are some virtual keys which are not defined with `VK_` like: `0E-0F`.

Comment: AT chris I think I misinterpreted the sentence.
@Raindrop7 are they are not defined, can we class them as virtual keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misinterpreted the English grammar. The sentence in itself is ambiguous, but in a larger context it becomes clear.

The author wanted to say:

> - You usually use the virtual key codes, instead of the scan codes of the keys.
> - The virtual key codes have names starting with `VK_`.
> - The scan codes have names starting with `SC_`.

By the way, the exact reference is Chapter 6, section Keystroke Messages. The paragraph above your quote talks about scan codes and virtual key codes. The paragraph you quoted concentrates on the virtual key codes.

Comment: I edited my link to goto the correct page in the book.
So I guess all Virtual Keys do have names begining with `VK_`

Comment: @JackBoy: All virtual-key codes, **for which there are symbolic constants**, have symbolic constants that begin with `VK_`. [Virtual-key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx) are just numbers after all, and there are codes, for which there aren't any symbolic constants defined (e.g. `0` - `9`, or `A` - `z`).